# Apply function on all matrix elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to apply a function on each element in a matrix. I've written the following code:

```
function p = an(x)
    p= x + 1;
end
```

The matrix is for example:

```
B = [1 2 3; 3 4 5; 6 7 8]
```

When I try to do this:

```
arrayfun(@an , B(1, :) , B(2, :), B(3, :))
```

I get this error:

> `??? Error using ==> arrayfun
>
>   Undefined function or method 'an' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

I can't understand why. How I can fix it? Is there a easier way to do it?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Main problem

> `Undefined function or method 'an' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

This means that MATLAB doesn't recognize your function `an`. Make sure that `an` is implemented in a separate m-file called `an.m`, and that it is located in your current working directory.

#### Additional problem

I can see that your `arrayfun` syntax is flawed. Once you solve your current problem, I predict that you will encounter another error message:

> `??? Error using ==> an
>
>   Too many input arguments.`

The problem is that function `an` accepts only one input argument, but you're passing three arguments in `arrayfun`. Instead, either pass only one argument, for example:

```
arrayfun(@an, B);
```

or modify `an` to accept three arguments, for example:

```
function p = an(x, y, z)
    p = x + y + z
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so it's up to you to choose.

Comment: I have one more question:
if i will change the "an" function to:
function ans = an(x)
if x == 1
    ans = x+1;
else
    ans = x+2;
end
end

How can I apply this function on each cell of the matrix?
(I've tried to write:
          arrayfun(@an,B)
but it doesn't work.

thank you .

Comment: @user1943029 you're using the variable `ans` which is already [reserved keyword](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ans.html). Use another name and it should work.

Comment: It doesnt work with another name.
Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Can you give more details about "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?